# CSS-Grid -OR- Reactjs breaks Object-fit:contain?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I am using CSS Grid to build an image gallery modal. Clickable thumbnails will call up images in the larger "main view" container. The problem is that no matter what I try, the image either: 1) overflows its container and pushes the thumbnail gallery out of the modal or 2) acts as a cover-sized image, cropping all images to the same dimensions.

What I *need* to have happen, is for all images—portrait or landscape—to be contained within the grid area when featured, so that the entire image is available.

I'm writing this in React, so I am also wondering if there is a conflict on that end.

So far, NOTHING has worked to contain the image inside of the featured img window. Here's what I've tried:
1. combinations of `width` and `max-height` OR `max-width:` and `height`
2. `object-fit: contain` and `object-fit: scale-down`. I have actually tried many other versions of this to see if it makes any differences, and it literally has no effect on the output. 
3. Setting the `<img>` tag inside of a div wrapper and constraining that div to the size of the grid area container
4. Making the `<img>` itself the grid item to fit in the grid area.

```css
.grid_container--modal {
  /* notice the short height is not being kept. */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(25px,1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 6fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h h h"
    "i i i i c c"
    "g g g g c c";
}

.modal-header {
  grid-area: h;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.modal-feature {
  /* i is for "image" */
  grid-area: i;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-feature-img {
  /* with explicit measures this only sort of works.*/
  max-width: 100%;
}

.modal-info {
  grid-area: c;
  background: tomato;
 }
 

.modal-gallery {
  grid-area: g;
  background: mediumseagreen;
 }
 
 .thumbnail {
 max-width: 50px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 5px;
 padding: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid_container--modal'>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h1>header content</h1>
  </div>
  
  <!-- HERE'S WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES -->
  <div class="modal-feature">
    <img class='modal-feature-img' src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/any' />
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal-info">
  Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.
  </div>
  <div class="modal-gallery">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/eee/333">
  </div>
</div>
```

**As of right now,** This is working like a cover background or like `object-fit: cover` and cropping my images, but (at least) not overflowing the container and pushing other things out. I need it to not crop the images and for them to contain within the grid area.

Comment: You can fix this with css. But please add a [mcve]. A typical trick is to set the image's width or/and height to 0 with css, so that the grid (or flex) container only expands to the image's intrinsic size.

Comment: To create a minimal example, get rid of the irrelevant code, and use the "snippet" feature of the editor. This is a css problem, so the jsx/react code is not needed. Just use html in the snippet.

Comment: Haken, as I need content in the grid to display the issue, I have really tried to narrow this down to the essentials. I have tried setting width/height/both to 0 and it didn't affect my output. 

I have put it into a snippet, however, and removed all JSX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want as output. But I think you should use `object-contain` on the featured img as well. I changed the total height from 100px to 300px, because with a total grid height of 100px, there would be no room for the featured image at all.

```css
.grid_container--modal {
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, minmax(25px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 6fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-areas: "h h h h h h" "i i i i c c" "g g g g c c";
}

.modal-header {
  grid-area: h;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.modal-feature {
  /* i is for "image" */
  grid-area: i;
  min-height: 0;
}

.modal-feature-img {
  /* use 100% to stretch to fit parent */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.modal-info {
  grid-area: c;
  background: tomato;
}

.modal-gallery {
  grid-area: g;
  background: mediumseagreen;
}

.thumbnail {
  max-width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid_container--modal'>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h1>header content</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- HERE'S WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES -->
  <div class="modal-feature">
    <img class='modal-feature-img' src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/any' />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-info">
    Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.
  </div>
  <div class="modal-gallery">
    <img class='thumbnail' src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals' />
    <img class='thumbnail' src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/people' />
    <img class='thumbnail' src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech' />
    <img class='thumbnail' src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/architecture' />

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you just created there is exactly the output I am after. But even using that exact code in my file, it isn't working. It always creates a "cover" image, so that other files. Object-fit: contain SHOULD be the solution, which is the purpose for this post. The small height (100px) was jus to point out that despite a small height, the image overflows the container and expands the grid, rather than being contained in its parent.

Comment: So it looks right in the snippet here on stack overflow, but not in your app? That might be caused by some other css file that possibly interferes. Use your web browser's dev tools to investigate.